# Hex to Dec conversion (pipe with sed)

Tags: sed, hex

How can I convert my Hex value to Dec value using pipe after `sed`.

Conversion from 'litte endian' to 'big endian'

```
dec_value=`echo dede0a01 | sed 's,\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\),\4\3\2\1,g'`
```

**Update:**

This works fine:

```
endi=`echo dede0a01 | sed 's,\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\),\4\3\2\1,g' | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'`
echo "ibase=16; $endi" | bc
```

But I'm curious whether this is possible with one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your `tr` before the `sed` and have `sed` add the `ibase=16;` before piping it all into `bc`:

```
dec_value=$(echo dede0a01 | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' | sed 's,\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\),ibase=16;\4\3\2\1,g' | bc)
```

If you're using Bash, ksh or zsh, you don't need `tr` and `bc`:

```
(( dec_value = 16#$(echo dede0a01 | sed 's,\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\),\4\3\2\1,g') ))
```

or without `echo` and `sed`, too:

```
hex=dede0a01
(( dec_value = 16#${hex:6:2}${hex:4:2}${hex:2:2}${hex:0:2} ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that doesn't shell out to `bc`, and uses only portable, standard syntax, nothing Bash, zsh, or ksh specific:

```
dec_value=`echo dede0a01 | sed 's,\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\),\4\3\2\1,g' | (read hex; echo $(( 0x${hex} )))`
```

Or, somewhat more simply:

```
: $(( dec_value = 0x$(echo dede0a01 | sed 's,\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\),\4\3\2\1,g') ))
```

(You need the `: $((...))` to be portable; `$((...))` substitutes its result, and the `:` allows you to ignore it. In Bash and likely ksh/zsh, you could just use `((...))`)

Answer (score 0):

`bc` accepts all caps. Assuming you can provide it all caps:

```
endi=`echo DEDE0A01 | sed 's,\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\),\4\3\2\1,g'`
echo "obase=10; $endi" | bc
```

Prints `1099999`

Else if you run `bc` before you convert, it prints `99990901`.

Comment: That's converting the hex value dede0a01 to decimal. But first i need to convert it to 01a0eded (using sed) and then convert it to decimal. So how can i use bc after sed ?

Comment: You mean convert 'dede0a01' to '10a0eded' not '01a0eded', or not?

Comment: Use `bc` before you convert then!. Ultimately you will need to use `bc`, before or after.

Comment: dec_value=`echo dede0a01 | sed 's,\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\),\4\3\2\1,g'` makes the conversion to: 010adede (sorry for the typo). After that i need to convert that to 17489630. So how can is use a pipe after sed to make the conversion from 010adede to 17489630 ? Tried bc but can get it work.

Comment: It appears that your hex code is not valid, cuz' bc accepts all caps.

Comment: When i use: 
  echo "ibase=16; 010ADEDE" | bc 
(ibase instead of obase, and all capital) the conversion works. 
But i want to add the conversion after sed. 
So how to use a pipe after sed and then bc.

If that's not possible i can use a variable with bc.
Tried that already but bc doesn't seems to accept a variable.